# Runge-Kutta method for linear ODEs

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a generic question:

Can the Runge - Kutta method be used to solve every type of linear ordinary differential equation?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this method is used to solve IVP so boundary condition is needed. It is not limited to linear equations and I am not aware of specific restrictions although any numerical scheme may be unstable depending on the equation.

Comment: By linear ODE do you mean of the form $$\boldsymbol{Y}' = {\bf A} \boldsymbol{Y} + \boldsymbol{b}$$

Comment: Hi.  By linear, I mean odes that are linear in y(x) and its derivatives.  Also, no terms where y(x) is multiplied by its derivatives.

Comment: See [slide 30](https://cims.nyu.edu/~donev/Teaching/SciComp-Fall2019/Lecture-ODE.handout.pdf)